# Invoke android phone profile mode at specific time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, profile, broadcast

how to change the **android phone profile mode** automatically at specific time.

**I want to develope an application which changes set up a schedule and at that specific schedules time, profile mode automatically change to desired mode.**

*how can i do it* ?

Comment: I tried to learn broadcastReceiver and saw some tutorials to learn that how to send broadcast to broadcastReceiver.